# sql implementation in pandas

Tags: pandas, postgresql

I am trying to update a table with new names. There is a translation table with the old_field_names and new_field_names. Essentially, this is the operation I would like to do on pandas, if I have two dataframes. Two conditions must be met (field_id, level_id). Merge seems to work on only one.

```
UPDATE migration.profile tbl1
   SET field_id = new_field_id,
       level_id = new_level_id
  FROM migration.translation_old_new tbl2
 WHERE tbl1.field_id = tbl2.field_id
   AND tbl1.level_id = tbl2.level_id
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandasql - https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/
You can write sql on dataframes